# Facebook Posted Video URL not showing Play button on thumbnail

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post link which has image/video both and also adding thumbnail of that video but somehow video thumbnail has no play button for video is showing on facebok post.

I am using graph API for posting video as link below is my code.

```
await (await CreateAppClientAsync()).PostTaskAsync($"/v2.8/{userId}/feed/", new  {message,"http://content.bequeathit.com/content/bequeaths/225d5ec2-79d5-451f-b6da-609ff0479cd9.mp4",name = linkTitle,picture = "http://content.bequeathit.com/content/bequeaths/cef0189a-400a-49c9-9071-31ea7089324e.mp4",caption = linkCaption,description = linkDescription,});
```

I am posting this via C# class and using sdk of facebook there.

anything i have missed where i am posting my link as video ? please help me for the same

Comment: Your video URL needs to be HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for the reply. I have two more questions 1. is this possible to display large size thumbnail with same code ? If my video thumbnail size is small but i wanted to display it on full size. 2. How to autoplay video on click of full screen size ?

Comment: 1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images 2. When the user clicks somewhere, it is not autoplay. Unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: 1. As per link we can need to resize image before posting to FB right ? 2. Yes when user click on that video from FB newsfeed it is opening to another window in mobile phone and play when viewing it on webbrowser from computer. i want it to autoplay when user click on that in mobile phone

Comment: Are you posting the URL of the video as the `link` now? That’s not how it works. You need to share the URL to an HTML document, that has the video embedded via OG meta tags.

Comment: Yes, i have added URL directly there. ok so i need to create one HTML page with embaded URL of video to play and hosted it somewhere and then provide link in FB post right ?

Comment: Yes. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video In case of problems, use the debug tool first to check if your meta data is ok (and also to update Facebook’s cache, after you made changes.) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138105/discussion-between-brijesh-and-cbroe).

Comment: Thanks for this help. sorry but i did't get this one : "and also to update Facebook’s cache, after you made changes."

Comment: When i am creating HTML page and passing it to FB post it will recognize video and display play button over thumbnail if image then it will not display play button.

Comment: Facebook caches the meta data it reads from external URLs. If you make changes to the meta data of your URL, put it through the debug tool to refresh the cache.